# Push to array with angular-flickity and flickity

Tags: angularjs, flickity

I am using ng-repeat on 3 elements, I want to push a dynamic item every 30 seconds,

the problem is that when I push an element to the array, the carousel get stuck and not reflect the current state of items in the ng-repeat.

The solution that I found is:

1.Destroy current carousel using FlickityService.

2.Push new elements to array.

3.Recreate the carousel using FlickityService.

The problem with the above workaround is that it is very clanky and demand destruction of DOM elements and recreating it over and over again-very expensive solution.
I have simulate this problem with current codepen:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['bc.Flickity']);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope,FlickityService,$document,$interval){
    var counter = 4;
    $scope.myCustomOptions = {
      cellSelector: '.carousel-cell',
      initialIndex: 1,
      prevNextButtons: true,
    };
  
    $scope.items = [{
      Name: "Name1"
    },{
      Name: "Name2"
    },{
      Name: "Name3"
    }];
  
  angular.element($document[0]).ready(() => {
     var element =             angular.element(document.getElementById('carousel-container'));

    // Initialize our Flickity instance
    FlickityService.create(element[0], element[0].id,$scope.myCustomOptions);
    
  });
  
  $interval(function(){
    $scope.items.push({Name:"Name"+counter});
  }, 30* 1000)

  });
```

```css
.carousel-cell {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.carousel-cell:before {
  display: block;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/metafizzy/flickity/master/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/metafizzy/flickity/master/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/benjamincharity/angular-flickity/master/dist/angular-flickity.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div id="carousel-container">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" class="carousel-cell">
        {{item.Name}}
      </div> 
  </div>  
</div>
```

The optimal solution in my opinion , is that flickity will get update instantly when I update my current array.

I would be happy for any kind of help.

Comment: you need to append the new element: https://github.com/benjamincharity/angular-flickity#adding-and-removing-cells

Comment: I am already familiar with this function, my problem with this function is that I need to send the entire element html over and over again, the same happen for deleting I need to send again the element html.It isn't intuitive approach, why flickity doesn't know how to handle ng-repeat update: remove or insert of elements??

Comment: the `bc-flickety` directive handles `ng-repeat` for you, but if you create your own flickety instance like you've done here, then you are responsible for it's children.  flickety itself isn't angular aware, so it would never be able to handle `ng-repeat`.

Comment: even the developers of the angular-flickety service use the same technique you are describing; of destroying and re-initializing the flickety instance.  https://codepen.io/benjamincharity/pen/qaGJmW?editors=0010.  Flickety wasn't written to expect the array of images to change.

Comment: thanks @Claies for the deatailed answer